# How to go to previous scene in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

basicly if the user has never played the game before i want it to take them to scene1, if they haven't i want it to take them to the previous scene they were on, how do i do this.

I've been trying a while and heres the code i came up with and I;m sure it is nothing like it should be but the problem is i can't find an answer, any help? thanks!

```
 local function onSceneTouch( event )
    if event.phase == "ended" then
       scene = storyboard.getPrevious()
       if scene == "main" then
         storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", "slideLeft", 500 ) else
         storyboard.gotoScene( --what goes here? previous scene?, "slideLeft", 500)
         return true
       end
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
local previousScene=storyboard.getPrevious()
storyboard.gotoScene(previousScene)
```

Comment: That worked thank you, also because my main.lua wasn't really a scene i replaced "main" with nil

Comment: @IqraDar thanx for great answer, its working for me too. But i have one more problem, when i go back to previous Scene, the next scene view is still visible in previous scene. can you help something?
Thanx

Comment: Have you added the elements of the next screen to group on the createScene or enterScene? By group, I mean the `group=self.view` line code that should be inside of these methods.